# Still running script (block layered indexation) on server

Tags: cron, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Prestashop Version: 1.5.4.1

We are updating products (discounts, categories etc.) in PS by a database bridge from Money accounting system and after that we are running a few crons, but problem is only with this one:

> http://*******/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered-price-indexer.php?token=******&full=1

In apache running scripts view is this script opened several times. I tried put `exit()` on the end of file but no change...

Do you have any ideas where can be problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved... 
Problem is that PS will at first find how many products want to index (for example 900), then run indexation for first 100 and call himself again, with cursor on 200. If was reached timelimit (which is FORCED set to 5!!!!!) or memory peak etc, script will call again himself with same cursor and that is the problem -> rewriting timelimit to 80 (in our server case solved the problem).